# Work-around about the quantitative limitation of websocket in IE

Tags: websocket, internet-explorer-11, aws-iot

I have a project which may need open many tabs at the same time. And in each tab, there are at least 2 websocket. In some old version of IE11, the max number of websocket is only 6. As a result, when I open more than 3 tabs, the websocket will down.

To solve this problem, I have tried some work-around. I assign different websockets to different domains so that I can open at least 6 tabs. Then I use localstorage to share the websocket message, so I only need one master tab to receive message and other tabs just need listen the storage event. But this will lead to some `qulity issue`, when the master tab disconnect or be closed, I need to vote a new master tab, during which period the messages will be lost. Unfortunately my software cannot tolerate the data loss.

PS: Since all the project is in aws, I use aws IoT to implement websocket and as far as I know aws IoT cannot make data persistence.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to set group policy which allows you to change the default limit of WebSocket connections per server. The default limit is 6; you can select a value from 2 through 128.

Please refer steps below to set this using group policy.

(1) Type gpedit.msc in Run window to open Local group policy editor.

(2) Navigate to location below.

```
Local Computer Policy > Computer Configuration > Administrative Templates >Windows Components > Internet Explorer > Security Features
> AJAX
```

(3) Find the setting named as **Set the maximum number of WebSocket connections per server**.

(4) double click on it to configure this setting.

(5) User can Enabled it and set the desired number of maximum connections between 2 to 128.

[image]

(6) click on OK to close the dialog.

(7) Restart the IE to take effect of changes.

Comment: Is this solution operated in client side and need user to do something? I hope to solve this problem from my code or framework instead of customer operation.

Comment: From our side we can try to provide support for IE browser. We are not aware about your code, framework or your server side settings. So we are not sure whether there are any settings that let you to this setting. You can try to provide more information about your issue. We will surely try to check and try to provide suggestions for that. Thanks for your understanding.